# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to deploy mod_wsgi with apache to run a django application but I am getting an error 500 internal server error The apache logs shows:

```
[Thu Jun 23 14:01:47 2011] [error] [client 152.78.95.64] mod_wsgi (pid=16142): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/bms/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Thu Jun 23 14:01:47 2011] [error] [client 152.78.95.64] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 23 14:01:47 2011] [error] [client 152.78.95.64]   File "/home/user/bms/apache/django.wsgi", line 13, in <module>
[Thu Jun 23 14:01:47 2011] [error] [client 152.78.95.64]     import django.core.handlers.wsgi
[Thu Jun 23 14:01:47 2011] [error] [client 152.78.95.64] ImportError: No module named django.core.handlers.wsgi
```

My apache virtual host is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/user/bms

    <Directory /home/user/bms>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess bms user=user group=user processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages


    WSGIProcessGroup bms

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/bms/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

And the referenced wsgi file in my app directory with 0777 permissions:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/user/bms'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bms.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I heard that this may be because the apache user does not have the correct permissions. However I have no idea how to fix this. I also tried starting the deamon with the www-data user and this did not solve the issue.

**EDIT**:

I solved this by copying the virtual hosts file into the default one and then disabling the old one with a2dissite. I have no idea how I can do it "properly" and set it so apache goes to the virtual host I want it to though.

Comment: Missing `site.addsitedir('/path/to/your/venv/python2.7/site-packages/')` in your WSGI-app configuration script?

Answer (score 82):

For me the problem was wsgi python version mismatch. I was using python 3, so:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Warning from @alxs **before you copy/paste** these commands:
If there are python 2 projects running on the server that use wsgi and apache, the above commands will effectively shut them down.

Comment: Before someone copies/pastes the above, note that if there are python 2 projects running on the server that use wsgi and apache, the above commands will effectively shut them down.

Comment: @alxs So I guess there's no way to run Python 2 and 3 projects on Apache?

Comment: @User I haven't tried to do something like that tbh, so I can't really tell. Maybe this answers your question though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375520/wsgi-apps-with-python-2-and-python-3-on-the-same-server. In any case, it could prove troublesome (if it's possible) and given that Python 2 is [officialy not maintaiined anymore](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), I think it would be a good choice to consider moving to Python 3.

Comment: This solution finally helped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 23):

For me the issue was that the WSGI script wasn't executable.

```
sudo chmod a+x django.wsgi
```

or just

```
sudo chmod u+x django.wsgi
```

so long as you have the correct owner

Comment: Who should be the owner of `wsgi.py`? I have `root` set as group/owner.

Comment: Sorry I can't remember. That was back in 2013. Try `sudo chmod a+x django.wsgi` and that will allow execution no matter who tries to run it. If that works then some searching on google might turn up the answer.

Comment: where is the django.wsgi file?

Comment: Well for the Op, the file is located at /home/user/bms/apache/django.wsgi. You may need to use the "locate" (or mlocate) command: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/locate-command-examples/

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with this error message in the logs:

> Target WSGI script '/home/web2py/wsgihandler.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

The solution was the deletion of an incorrect WSGIPythonHome directive (pointing to the application directory) from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`

I'm on RedHat using CentOS repositories.

Recommend following Graham Dumpleton's installation/configuration instructions. Testing configuration against the helloworld application showed me that `mod_wsgi` was working and the configuration was at fault.

However, the error message gave little clue as to what was wrong.

Comment: After the "Target WSGI script '/home/web2py/wsgihandler.py' cannot be loaded as Python module." line in log there should have been a bunch of other stuff including Python traceback and exception message. There should have been a lot more information than that, that is only the first line and not the real information.

Comment: Solved my issue after paying close attention to the traceback, listen to @GrahamDumpleton because he's right.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and at first I didn't realise I could scroll further down and see the actual error message. In my case, it was an import error:

```
ImportError: No module named bootstrap3
```

After installing it via pip (pip install django-bootstrap3), I restarted Apache and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Appending path in `wsgi.py` is the direction, but instead of appending `django` appending path `sys.path.append("/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages")` fixed my case.

This is for a django project using python2.7 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is pretty old, but I wrestled with this for about eight hours just now. If you have a system with SELinux enabled and you've put your virtualenv in particular places, mod_wsgi won't be able to add your specified `python-path` to the site-packages. It also won't raise any errors; as it turns out the mechanism it uses to add the specified `python-path` to the site packages is with the Python `site` module, specifically `site.adduserdir()`. This method doesn't raise any errors if the directory is missing or can't be accessed, so mod_wsgi also doesn't raise any errors.

Anyway, try turning off SELinux with

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

or by making sure that the process you're running Apache as has the appropriate ACLs with SELinux to access the directory the virtualenv is in.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it without the WSGIDaemonProcess option?

I had no trouble setting up mod_wsgi at home, but did it without the daemon option.  You mentioned solving by moving around virtual hosts files and I note this caveat in the docs for WSGIDaemonProcess:

> Also note that the name of the daemon
>   process group must be unique for the
>   whole server. That is, it is not
>   possible to use the same daemon
>   process group name in different
>   virtual hosts.

Don't know if that's coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

In my own case on windows in xampp, I was incorrectly loading the application path in the wsgi.py file like so:

***Incorrect***:

```
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "advisory_portal.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
sys.path.append('C:/xampp/htdocs/advisory_portal/advisory_portal')
sys.path.append('C:/xampp/htdocs/advisory_portal')
```

Instead of:

***Correct:***

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/xampp/htdocs/advisory_portal/advisory_portal')
sys.path.append('C:/xampp/htdocs/advisory_portal')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "advisory_portal.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Don't forget to import sys python package

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error. I'm using python 3 in a virtual environment
found this in my apache logs

> [Fri Dec 21 08:01:43.471561 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21786]
>   AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) mod_wsgi/3.4
>   Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

I had installed wsgi using `yum -y install mod_wsgi`. This had installed mod_wsgi compiled for python 2. So I uninstalled it

```
yum remove mod_wsgi
```

and installed mod_wsgi compiled for python 3 using

```
yum install python35u-mod_wsgi
```

It worked after that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error

> Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

This was because the python path was not added in the apache.conf

Depending on the Apache and Ubuntu version you need to update the apache.conf or httpd.conf file with the pythonWSGIPath

In my case I need to edit the apache.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line at the end (Change the my_project to the project your project name)

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/my_project
```

And everything works with charm

Answer (score 0):

As this question became sort of a pool for collecting solutions for problems that result in the error giving this question its title, I'd like to add this one, too.

In my case, I want to run OpenStack Keystone (Ocata) using Apache and WSGI on Ubuntu 16.04.2. The processes start but as soon as I query keystone I get

```
mod_wsgi (pid=20103): Target WSGI script '/opt/openstack/bin/keystone-wsgi-public' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

I had two vhosts, one had

```
WSGIDaemonProcess keystone-public ...
WSGIProcessGroup keystone-public ...
```

while the other had

```
WSGIDaemonProcess keystone-admin ...
WSGIProcessGroup keystone-admin ...
```

I solved the problem by renaming them. The vhost entries now read:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess kst-pub ...
WSGIProcessGroup kst-pub ...
```

and

```
WSGIDaemonProcess kst-adm ...
WSGIProcessGroup kst-adm ...
```

I didn't investigate any further. Solved as works for me.

Comment: As the author of mod_wsgi I know of no length limitation on the name of the process group. I would suspect the problem was elsewhere and your restart of Apache probably resolved it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Maybe, but that had to be a problem that is implicitly fixed with an apache restart, because it was a fresh deployment and the config files came from my repository. I definetly only changed these four lines between restarts. Not unlikely though! Maybe keystone trips over not existing log files and or directories which are implicitly created, but too late. After a restart these files/directories are there.

Answer (score 0):

If you install your project’s Python dependencies inside a virtualenv, you’ll need to add the path to this virtualenv’s directory to your Python path as well. To do this, add an additional path to your WSGIPythonPath directive, with multiple paths separated by a colon (:) if using a UNIX-like system, or a semicolon (;) if using Windows

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the list this is how I got it working.

I was trying to install CKAN 2.7.2 on CentOS 7 from source and kept coming up against this error.
For me it was because SELinux was enabled. I didn't need to disable it. Instead, after reading https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2010/10/13/selinux-httpd-modwsgi-26-rhel-centos-5, I found that turning on httpd_can_network_connect fixed it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

From that page:

> **httpd_can_network_connect** - Allows httpd to make network connections,
>   including the local ones you'll be making to a database

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue eg apache log error "wsgi.py cannot be loaded as Python module."

It turned out I had to stop and then start apache instead of just restarting it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it got solved using

```
sudo easy_install cx_Oracle
```

but remember to unistall cx_oracle before installing it using `easy_install`.

Command to uninstall:  `pip uninstall cx_oracle`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that finally worked for me, after trying many of these options unsuccessfully was simple, but elusive because I struggled to figure out what actual paths to use.

I created a mezzanine project, which is based on django, with the following commands. I list them here to make the paths explicit.

```
/var/www/mysite$ python3 -m venv ./venv
/var/www/mysite$ source ./venv/bin/activate
(venv) /var/www/mysite$ mezzanine-project mysite
(venv) /var/www/mysite$ cd mysite
(venv) /var/www/mysite/mysite$
```

Now, the path to the wsgi.py file is:

```
/var/www/mysite/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

The directives that worked for this installation within my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` file follow:

```
...<VirtualHost...>
    ...
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/var/www/mysite/venv python-path=/var/www/mysite/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py process-group=accounting
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>...
```

I tried numerous versions of python-home and python-path and got the OP's error repeatedly. Using the correct paths here should also accomplish the same things as [@Dev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207725/2846766) without having to add paths in the wsgi.py file (supplied by [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/), and no editing necessary in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when I get stuck on this I hard code a path to project in the wsgi file like:

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.append("/var/www/html/myproject")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying to downgrade DJANGO to version `2.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure my project's `venv` folder resides inside my project's root directory solved this problem for me.