# ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I'm moving a web application from a Windows environment to CentOS 5.11 and Apache, and with everything installed, I'm receiving a `500` when I try to load up the site. The error log shows this:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5461): Target WSGI script '/usr/local/treehouse/wsgi/index.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=5461): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/treehouse/wsgi/index.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/treehouse/wsgi/index.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.wsgi'
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14927345/2069350) (and the related ones), which appears to be similar but none of the answers there fix the issue. I'm *not* running in a `virtualenv`, and django appears to be installed correctly, as I can run the offending statement:

```
>>> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
```

in the interactive Python interpreter and it works *just fine*. Here's the script causing the error (it's just the default `index.wsgi` that you see everywhere you look for this stuff):

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/treehouse/apple')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/treehouse/apple/apple')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "apple.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Obviously the last line causes the error, but here's the fun part: the last line *remains* the problem, even if I add this just above it:

```
import django.core
import django.core.handlers
```

Both of the underlying packages import without a hitch (`django.core.wsgi` is just a thin wrapper around some functionality in `django.core.handlers.wsgi`). It's only when I try to access the `wsgi` packages that problems occur. Inspecting `sys.path` within this script shows all the right directories (`/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`, etc.). And again, running the exact same code from the interactive interpreter causes no errors.

I tried an uninstall/reinstall of django (`pip install django==1.6.5`), then I reset the VM to a totally clean snapshot and rebuilt/reinstalled *everything*, and still I get the exact same behavior.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Some of the django source files pulled down by `pip` are saved with *Windows line endings*: that is, they end with `\r\n` rather than `\n`. On *nix systems, this has the effect of breaking imports in affected files, because instead of looking for `django.core.wsgi`, it tries to import `django.core.wsgi\r`.

This is why `django.core.handlers` can still be imported: the `__init__.py` file is empty, so there are no line endings to corrupt.

To fix it, run `dos2unix` on affected files. I'm not sure how many files are actually affected (except that it's many of them) so I just hit all of them with a quick Python script from the interpreter:

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, join

for root, _, files in os.walk('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django'):
    for f in files:
        os.system('dos2unix %s' % abspath(join(root, f)))
```

*Et voilà*, no more import errors!

---

### Storytime

I stumbled on this issue after I began hacking on the `django` source files in desperation. I edited `django/core/__init__.py` (normally empty) by adding this:

```
from . import wsgi
```

I modified `index.wsgi` to include this:

```
import django.core
django.core.wsgi  # no-op to see if we can access it
```

and ended up with a fascinating new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/treehouse/wsgi/index.wsgi", line 11, in <module>
    import django.core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import wsgi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
ImportError: No module named 'django.core.handlers.wsgi'
```

So from within `django/core/__init__.py`, I can access `django/core/wsgi.py`. But `django.core.handlers.wsgi` is out of reach. I deleted the changes to reproduce the original error--but the error had changed. Now I was getting the `No module named 'django.core.handlers.wsgi'` even without the explicit relative import.

This was when it hit me. I opened up `django/core/handlers/wsgi.py` in gedit, clicked the end of a line, pressed the spacebar, deleted the insertion, and saved the file. It should have been a no-op. But when I restarted the server, suddenly the import error had moved on to a different django import. The only logical explanation was that the line endings were wrong, and by re-saving the file in gedit, I was silently fixing them.