# deploy django application with pipenv on apache

Tags: python, django, pipenv, django-deployment

I have created a python web application in `Django 2.0` using `pipenv` virtualenv

Now, I have to host it on apache server. I have installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` and `python-setuptools` in the server.

The structure of my application is like

```
myapp_dir
 |- myapp
    |- settings
       |- __init__.py
       |- production.py
    |- __init__.py
    |- urls.py
    |- wsgi.py
 |- otherapp
 |- templates
 |- static_my_project
 |- manage.py
 |- Pipfile
 |- Pipfile.lock
```

the path of the application to put on

```
/home/user/app.application.com/
```

I have moved all files to the directory and installed all dependencies from `Pipfile` by running in the directory

```
pipenv install
```

This has created a virtualenv and installed all required modules and the path of `pipenv --venv` gives

```
# pipenv --venv
/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/app.application.com-IuTkL8w_
```

My `VirtualHost` configuration looks like

```
ServerName app.application.com
ServerAlias app.application.com

ErrorLog /home/user/error.log
CustomLog /home/user/custom.log combined

Alias /static /home/user/app.application.com/static_my_project
<Directory /home/user/app.application.com/static_my_project>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/app.application.com/pricearbitrase>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/app.application.com/myapp/wsgi.py
```

VirtualInclude contains

```
<IfModule mod_wsgi>

    WSGIPythonHome /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/app.application.com-IuTkL8w_

</IfModule>
```

**But on accessing `http://app.application.com` it gives `Internal server error` and the log file generated contains**

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730] mod_wsgi (pid=60730): Target WSGI script '/home/amzitrage/app.amzitrage.com/pricearbitrase/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730] mod_wsgi (pid=60730): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/amzitrage/app.amzitrage.com/pricearbitrase/wsgi.py'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730]   File "/home/amzitrage/app.amzitrage.com/pricearbitrase/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[wsgi:error] [pid 60730] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

> Edit 2

**app/wsgi.py**
modified `wsgi.py` file to activate `virtual environment`

```
activate_this = '/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/app.application.com-IuTkL8w_/bin/activate_this.py'
exec(compile(open(activate_this,"rb").read(),activate_this, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "application.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Also, `ls -l /path_to_pipenv_venv/bin` gives

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927345/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-apache-virtualenv-aws-wsgi

Comment: removed `/bin` still same error

Comment: @Alasdair do I need to rerun server after removing `/bin`?

Comment: You also appear to be missing `WSGIPythonPath` (see the example in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)), but that would cause issues loading `myapp`, not `django`.

Comment: If I set `WSGIPythonPath` what will be the path of this configuration

Comment: removed `/bin`, restarted server. still getting same error

Comment: It’s the path to the project directory (the one that contains `manage.py`).

Comment: If removing `/bin` didn’t help, I’m afraid I don’t have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to get it working.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I made a symbolic link to pipenv virtualenv to `myapp_dir/venv` just for convenience when using in apache files. 
Main problem I encountered are permissions.

If your virtualenv path is `/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/app.application.com-IuTkL8w_` then try this:

```
sudo -u www-data cat /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/app.application.com-IuTkL8w_/bin/activate_this.py`
```

Where `www-data` is your apache user.

If you get permission denied it's probably the same problem. 
Just try changing permissions of `~/.local` and `~/.local/share` that apache process can access them.

Just be advised that this is a development setup and in production I wouldn't use pipenv. I would just generate `requirements.txt` and setup a normal virtualenv or use gunicorn or something similar.