# How to fix 'Interner Server Error (500)' when start 'mod_wsgi-express starts-server myapp/wsgi.py'

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using python 3.5, django 2.*, apache2 in ubuntu.
It's success when I 'runserver' my django project and using 'mod_wsgi-express start-server', malt wisky(?) page appear well on the screen.
But using command 'mod_wsgi-express start-server myapp/wsgi.py', '500 Internal Server Error' appeared.
There is no log on var/log/apache2/access.log and error.log. And the Ubuntu terminal also doesn't show any messages.

What are the causes?
Just let me know what you think.

Comment: I found logs in /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhos:8000:1000/error_log file. "Importerror: No module named 'django' error appeared. So I reinstalled django in python venv but not disappeared... I'll find some more...  ㅠ_ㅠ

Comment: Succeeded with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927345/importerror-no-module-named-django-core-wsgi-apache-virtualenv-aws-wsgi). Thanks!!