# apache wsgi django path issue frustration

Tags: python, django, apache, path, mod-wsgi

I have read similar questions/answers but I cant resolve the situation. So I have installed WSGI and want to serve my django app from Apache.

What I did initially was to create with virtualenv the folder testing which holds the python related stuff. So I did

```
  virtualenv environment
```

My vhost file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-path=/var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/:/var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/environment/lib/python2.7/:/var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/environment/lib/python2.7/sites-available
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing/wsgi.py
...
...
```

My wsgi.py is:

```
 import os

 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")

 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Once visiting the webpage I am getting a Server Internal Error and the error.log says 2 error messages basically:

```
 [wsgi:error] [pid 31165] [client 192.168.0.3:31337] mod_wsgi (pid 31165): Target WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/myapp.com/testing/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python Module
```

and right after several lines that end to:

```
 [wsgi:error] [pid 31165] [client 192.168.0.3:31337] mod_wsgi (pid 31165): ImportError: Could not import settings 'testing.settings' (is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?)
```

I found regarding the first error msg this  [Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module) however I couldnt resolve the issue. What I get is that this error is not stopping Apache from trying to load my python (django) project since the next error is what I think causes the 500 response. For the second error I found that is a matter of adding the paths (something that I have done to my vhost file! ?)

I tried other solutions such as adding the WSGIPythonPath on my apache.conf but didnt work.

My wsgi.py file is as follows:

```
 import os
 os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")

 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I also tried adding

```
  import sys
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
  sys.path.append('/var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing')
  import mysite.settings
```

didnt work.

Comment: Do you get any error messages if you execute `python wsgi.py` in directory */var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing/*?

Comment: Yes. I am getting the same error with the Import-Error. Its definitely a path issue however I dont understand what I am doing wrong.. :(

Comment: If you have a more current version of *wsgi.py* (with `sys.path.append` etc.), it might be better to edit the question. Also, having a complete stack traceback might help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving *wsgi.py* and *settings.py* to */var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing/mysite*

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing
<VirtualHost *:8000>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing/mysite/wsgi.py
    # WSGIApplicationGroup is needed to prevent some problem?
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

and in the *wsgi.py* file

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
sys.path.append('/var/www/vhosts/myapp/testing')
import mysite.settings
```

I think I had similar issues when I upgraded django. Things started working after I relocated *settings.py* and *wsgi.py*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didnt work though :( Same error msgs.

Comment: @user3124171 I had put also some related lines in `wsgi.py`, I forgot to put them here

Comment: These lines I have found them also on another thread. However these do not work for me... I dont know what is happening :( I am cursed