# Django project on apache giving error

Tags: django, apache

I am trying to run a django project on apache web server. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to setup the server with my django project. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and my project is located in a virualenv on my desktop.

My /000-default.conf settings:

```
Alias /static /home/manish/Desktop/starchi/ekomerz/static
<Directory /home/manish/Desktop/starchi/ekomerz/static>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/manish/Desktop/starchi/ekomerz/ekomerz>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess ekomerz python-path=/home/manish/Desktop/starchi/ekomerz:/home/manish/Desktop/starchi/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup ekomerz
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/manish/Desktop/starchi/ekomerz/ekomerz/wsgi.py
```

But it is giving me a `500 Internal Server Error`.
What am I doing wrong? I can run my project from my virtual environment.

EDIT:

[Error-Log](http://tempsend.com/02EAE56D8F)

Comment: You should check your logs to figure out what the actual error is.

Comment: @Sayse i uploaded error log. It says `Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module`. But couldn't figure out how to solve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module

Comment: I figured it out. It seems error was in my Log Handlers. The project was trying to write to root directory. So I gave absolute path in django.settings.