# Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/Django/bot/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2

i'm trying to devloping Django project. and i'm beginner.
suddenly, today my server does not work. i think i do nothing. so i don't understand what is the problem.

this is my /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=27808): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/Django/bot/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=27808): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/Django/bot/wsgi.py'.
```

and when I try to enterd my server http://MYURL, 500 Internal Server Error occur.

this is my wsgi.py code

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/Django')
#sys.path.append('/home/ubutu/Django/bot')
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/Django/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bot.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

since i create my project, i have done anything on my wsgi.py 
however the error occurred now.

Comment: hopefully this solves the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module

Comment: thanx... i found solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally find solution.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=27808): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/Django/bot/wsgi.py'.
```

this was not my critical problem.

above this error,

```
File "/home/ubuntu/Django/chat/admin.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Post'
```

I did some extra code on my admin.py
so someone who have problem, just like me, FIND REAL ERROR what you brought.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact error in my mod_wsgi and python environment. First of all,

> /var/log/apache2/error.log

file must be examined for the exact error. I changed my "wsgi.py" file contents to add paths below to my python path:

```
/home/user/project_name
/home/user/project_name/project_dir
/home/user/project_name/project_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

after this my problems have gone away. To cut it short, my problem was that I have a system with python 2.7 but my python environment is python 3.5 version. Hope it helps.