# 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wsgi, vesta

I'm getting this error in my logs with django app. I thought such errors occur when using Python 2.x, but in my virtual env **Python - 3.6.5**. **Django - 2.0.7**. VESTA Control Panel with wsgi. I will be grateful for the help.

**Error log:**

[Thu Jul 26 19:02:48 2018] [error] [client 86.32.36.143]   File "/home/project/private/django/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 61, in 
[Thu Jul 26 19:02:48 2018] [error] [client 86.32.36.143]     @functools.lru_cache()
[Thu Jul 26 19:02:48 2018] [error] [client 86.32.36.143] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

**django.wsgi**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/web/project/private/django/project/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/web/project/private/django/project/project/src/shared/')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/web/project/private/django/project/project/src/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'main.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: This needs more details to answer. e.g. line number, code.

Comment: Add your code and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue but then found out that my site was built with python3 and apache was configured for python2.7. The following link helped:
[Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module/28118284#28118284)