# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_wsgi.server'; 'mod_wsgi' is not a package

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run an Apache 2.4 server with mod_wsgi 4.5 and python 3.6/Django on my laptop running Ubuntu 18, but I'm getting a 500 error. The error is:

```
[Wed Oct 03 20:17:10.146305 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 15405:tid 140336693888768] [client 127.0.0.1:33306] mod_wsgi (pid=15405): Target WSGI script '/mnt/4e468d61-1820-41ad-8a44-8a356b024106/COP4331/server-side/webserver/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.


[Wed Oct 03 20:17:10.146362 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 15405:tid 140336693888768] [client 127.0.0.1:33306] mod_wsgi (pid=15405): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/mnt/4e468d61-1820-41ad-8a44-8a356b024106/COP4331/server-side/webserver/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.


[Wed Oct 03 20:17:10.147188 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 15405:tid 140336693888768] [client 127.0.0.1:33306] Traceback (most recent call last):

[...] (for brevity's sake)

[Wed Oct 03 20:17:33.631789 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 15404:tid 140336685496064] [client 127.0.0.1:33312]     import mod_wsgi.server


[Wed Oct 03 20:17:33.631805 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 15404:tid 140336685496064] [client 127.0.0.1:33312] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_wsgi.server'; 'mod_wsgi' is not a package
```

However, I definitely have mod_wsgi as a package- I've checked both my pip 2 and 3, and I've installed it for both.

I'm not using a virtual environment, so that's not a factor. I'm really at my wit's end here, so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module)

Comment: The solution there is that the person was using wsgi compiled for python2, but I made sure that my wsgi is compiled for python3.6. (I'm using py3.6)