# pgAdmin4 install - Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module) but the solution does not work for me. My python venv configuration is not playing well with the apache2 mod_wsgi and I cannot root-cause the issue. At present, I cannot comment on this question so I'm posting another one

Here are the apache2 error logs when trying to log into the site.

```
[Fri Dec 07 20:32:25.476491 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 25982:tid 140573456193408] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.
[Fri Dec 07 20:32:25.476529 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 25982:tid 140573456193408] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.
[Fri Dec 07 20:32:25.477326 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 25982:tid 140573456193408] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 07 20:32:25.477362 2018] [core:notice] [pid 25982:tid 140573456193408] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.401510 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047] mod_wsgi (pid=25983): Target WSGI script '/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.401642 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047] mod_wsgi (pid=25983): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi'.
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402195 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402229 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]   File "/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi", line 25, in <module>
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402236 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]     import config
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402244 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]   File "/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py", line 29, in <module>
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402248 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]     from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_PY2, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402256 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]   File "/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402260 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047]     from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
[Fri Dec 07 20:34:24.402280 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 25983:tid 140573343934208] [remote 10.2.5.243:15047] ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

Here is the Vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName shinyapp01t

    WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home=/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4 display-name=pgadmin4
    WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin /home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi

    <Directory "/home/awashburn/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/">
        WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I referenced [these instructions from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-pgadmin4-server-mode#step-6-%E2%80%94-creating-a-table-in-the-pgadmin-dashboard) trying to install pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit: I used a python3 venv instead of anaconda virtual env and everything worked fine. So the root cause is the anaconda system. [There's a discussion on the mod_wsgi mailing list about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/modwsgi/cannot$20import$20module%7Csort:date/modwsgi/w6-31hnZlBo/ijNVcn4YBgAJ)