# Deploying Flask app on own Ubuntu Server Error

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, flask

**GOAL** : I am trying to deploy my Flask app to make it public on the web. I have my own server which runs on Ubuntu 18.04

**TUTORIAL** : As it is the first time I am doing this, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY). All his steps are perfectly working for me except the last one. However, in this tutorial he used Linode and I use my own server so I directly code on my terminal

**PROBLEM** : In his last step after `systemctl reload apache2` when I go on the my browser and type my ip address (found using ifconfig) that I put in webApp.conf (192.168.1.25) I get the following error : 
[image]

**ERROR LOGS** : As asked I went into the error.log which outputs the following : 
[image]
You can find the code here : https://pastebin.com/g2rzRUXE

**POTENTIAL PROBLEMS**: From what I understand I am having two issues :

1. `Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message` . So I tried to solve it using this [tutorial](https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/tag/using-127-0-1-1-set-the-servername-directive-globally-to-suppress-this-message/) and I changed my private ip address to my public ip address (found on whatismyip.com) but when doing so I received the following error: [image: error]

   2. It does not seem to like my prints:
      [image: error2] . Am I not allowed to keep prints

Please let me know how I could solve these problems or the other ones in the error log that I might not have seen.

I hope I was clear enough. If you need any additional info I can edit my question. I am running out of ideas so if you have any tips I would be grateful.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454564/target-wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module

Comment: You are deploying a Python 3 application on a Python 2.7 virtualenv.

Comment: python 3 @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: @Pandurang I am using flask not django

Comment: @Reda, please, print the values of `sys.version` in your running application => in the logs, to be sure. You can add this in your `webapp.wsgi`.

Comment: Install python35u-mod_wsgi module and test.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) [GCC 7.3.0] is my output

Comment: Can you replace your screenshot by real code?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE the error log or the small screenshot ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/g2rzRUXE @LaurentLAPORTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logs, I can read:

```
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

So, you are using Python 2 instead of Python 3.

You need to install a `mod_wsgi` module compatible with Python 3.

Follow the instruction available here : https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html

The following link can also help: https://stackoverrun.com/fr/q/12335951 (in French).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It is working now.